# CentOs Tomcat MySQL TimeZone

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, centos, timezone

I changed CentOS timezone to Asia/Jakarta `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Jakarta`.

When I ran tomcat, I got error message on Tomcat :
`com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: No timezone mapping entry for 'WIB'`

I have already tried:

- to add mysql URL with `&amp;serverTimezone=WIB`
- to add in `my.cnf` this `default_time_zone=Asia/Jakarta`

But the error message still there.

Have anyone solution, how to solve this situiation?

Thank you.

Note: If I use UTC, I can run the application. But this is not the right timezone.

Environment:
JDBC 8.0.13
MySQL 8
Tomcat 9
CentOS 7

```
`16-Dec-2018 17:51:17.994 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-27] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] threw exception
 com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: No timezone mapping entry for 'WIB'
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor109.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2248)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2258)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1319)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:868)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:830)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at com.scsf.vd.sys.bs.mdl.hm.AbstractHm.getDataBeanByBeanId(AbstractDataBeanHome.java:139)
    at com.scsf.vd.sys.bs.mdl.hm.AbstractHm.getRegisteredCompanyName(AbstractPage.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:94)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:219)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:131)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:45)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:46)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:507)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1891)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:313)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.renderView(RewriteViewHandler.java:196)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler.handleResult(HttpRewriteResultHandler.java:42)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.rewrite(RewriteFilter.java:297)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.scsf.vd.sys.bs.mdl.hm.AbstractHm.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`
```

Comment: Please show us the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I edited the text above, please review once again.

Comment: just add `serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta` to your connection URL like: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?useSSL=true&serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta` it will be fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL contains some system tables containing the information necessary to handle time zones by name: `Asia/Jakarta` or `America/Halifax` or whatever. The source for that information is the so-called [Zoneinfo database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) that's part of most LInux distros including Centos.  The zoneinfo database takes into account all the electropolitical factors making up timezone and daylight saving rules; you and I don't have to figure that stuff out.

But the zoneinfo data must be loaded, from the distro, into MySQL. To find out whether that's the case try this command:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'UTC','Asia/Jakarta');
```

If you get an error, the zoneinfo database is not loaded into MySQL.

The procedure for loading it is shown here.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

You, or your server administrator, must use a shell command to create a mess of SQL INSERT statements and then use MySQL to run them:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

Comment: I ran the insert statement and got: `Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.`

Comment: Sounds like those  error messages came from the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` command. What happens if you repeat the `SELECT CONVERT_TZ...` command I suggested? If it works, you're in good shape.

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'UTC','Asia/Jakarta');` works fine.

Comment: I faced the same situation in MacOS and I have used this : `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta` and it works. But when I use the solution in CentOS, I get still no luck.

Comment: It's really confusing. I tried to change the timezone in CentOs to Asia/Jakarta and the URL for mysql changed to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true&amp;serverTimezone=Asia/Jakarta` and it works. I don't know, what or how to make it work, but it works. So now my server has the correct timezone :-)